# Sorting on date field with Sitecore 7 ContentSearch

Tags: lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

I'm trying to add a field sort to a date field in a ContentSearch query. I'm able to filter on the index field properly so I'm assuming the field is getting populated with values properly, however, results are not being sorted properly. Any thoughts? Here's the code I'm using to do query:

```
public static IEnumerable<Episode> GetPastEpisodes(Show show, bool includeMostRecent = false, int count = 0)
{
    IEnumerable<Episode> pastEpisodes;
    using (var context = _index.CreateSearchContext())
    {
        // querying against lucene index
        pastEpisodes = context.GetQueryable<Episode>().Where(GetPastAirDatePredicate(show));

        if(!includeMostRecent)
        {
            pastEpisodes = pastEpisodes.Where(item => item.Id != GetMostRecentEpisode(show).Id);
        }

        pastEpisodes = pastEpisodes.OrderByDescending(ep => ep.Latest_Air_Date);

        if (count > 0)
        {
            pastEpisodes = pastEpisodes.Take(count);
        }

        pastEpisodes = pastEpisodes.ToList();

        // map the lucene documents to Sitecore items using the database
        foreach (var episode in pastEpisodes)
        {
            _database.Map(episode);
        }

    }
    return pastEpisodes;
}

private static Expression<Func<Episode,bool>> GetPastAirDatePredicate(Show show)
{
    var templatePredicate = PredicateBuilder.Create<Episode>(item => item.TemplateId == IEpisodeConstants.TemplateId);
    var showPathPredicate = PredicateBuilder.Create<Episode>(item => item.FullPath.StartsWith(show.FullPath));
    var airDatePredicate = PredicateBuilder.Create<Episode>(item => item.Latest_Air_Date < DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1));

    var fullPredicate = PredicateBuilder.Create<Episode>(templatePredicate).And(showPathPredicate).And(airDatePredicate);

    return fullPredicate;
}
```

The field is stored and untokenized and using the `LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer`.

```
<field fieldName="latest_air_date" storageType="YES" indexType="UN_TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.DateTime" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
    <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider"/>
</field>
```

Episode class has `IndexField` attribute set:

```
[IndexField("latest_air_date")]
public virtual DateTime Latest_Air_Date  {get; set; }
```

Comment: Could you change type="System.DateTime" to type="System.String" and then rebuild your index and try again

Comment: @AhmedOkour Did not work, but thanks.

Comment: Kyle, could you confirm which rev of Sitecore you are testing this on?

Comment: just noticed that index type='UN_TOKENIZED', i think it should be indexType="untokenized".

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Kyle, did you find a solution yet?

Comment: @PascalMathys I'm trying to remember back now. I did find a solution. I think the problem in my case was that 'Latest_Air_Date' was a computed index field and the custom logic I was using to compute this field value was flawed.

Answer (score 1):

Kyle,

As far as I can tell everything looks correct with your configuration and code.  I mocked out something very similar in a vanilla Sitecore 7.2 instance and Dates sorted without issue.

One thing to note though, and this might be what is giving you some issues, is that Sitecore's FieldReader for DateTime only store the date portion of the DateTime.  If you are expecting to be able to sort by true DateTime you will need to add a custom FieldReader or some computed fields.

See this blog that discusses the issue and explains the process to swap out a custom field reader: http://reasoncodeexample.com/2014/01/30/indexing-datetime-fields-sitecore-7-content-search/

I would also suggest looking at the index with Luke to verify what data is actually in the index.  https://code.google.com/p/luke/

And finally you may want to enable Search debugging in Sitecore to see exactly how Sitecore is executing the query in Lucene.

Sitecore.ContentSearch.config:

```
<setting name="ContentSearch.EnableSearchDebug" value="true" />
```

Comment: Appreciate the tips. I did confirm that the values are storing properly using Luke and I am just looking at dates (not times). Will git the search debug a try.

Comment: Kyle, the search debug spits out a lot of info, feel free to add that output and I can compare to what I am seeing on my side.